# How to calculate current and voltage to heat up a wire?

Tags: voltage

I have a Cr20Ni80 nichrome wire having 1m length, 24 SWG and a resistance of 4.390 Ohm/m. I need to heat it up to 100 degree Celsius. How can I calculate the supply voltage and current for the purpose?

Comment: To calculate you need to know the heat off from the wire. Is it possible to use a laboratory power supply and measure the required values experimentally?

Answer (score 1):

The wire manufacturer should have available specifications/charts that give the required current to achieve a desired wire temperature for a certain wire size/type. Here is one example: http://wiretron.com/nichrome-resistance-wires/

You also have to take into account the wire mounting. For example if the wire is used as a single strand in free-air, or if it is to be wound on a core material. If the wire is in contact with a thermally conductive material more current is required to sustain a certain temperature.

Comment: The OP also needs to factor in the heat lost to the material being heated. (You may have been hinting at that in the last sentence.)